# Create dictionary with alphabet characters mapping to numbers

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

I want to write a code in Python, which assigns a number to every alphabetical character, like so: a=0, b=1, c=2, ..., y=24, z=25. I personally don't prefer setting up conditions for every single alphabet, and don't want my code look over engineered. I'd like to know the ways I can do this the shortest (meaning the shortest lines of code), fastest and easiest.
(What's on my mind is to create a dictionary for this purpose, but I wonder if there's a neater and better way).
Any suggestions and tips are in advance appreciated.

Comment: Your idea of the dictionary is correct. If someone pops up suggesting `locals()` or `globals()` then it's just bad design (I'm anticipating the answers)

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you. So that's the best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely want a dictionary for this, not to declare each as a variable. A simple way is to use a dictionary comprehension with `string.ascii_lowercase` as:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

{v:k for k,v in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I didn't like doing it manually and your solution solved my problem. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my two cents, for loop will do the work:

```
d = {} #empty dictionary

alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for i in range(26):
    d[alpha[i]] = i #assigns the key value as alphabets and corresponding index value from alpha string as the value for the key

print(d) #instant verification that the dictionary has been created properly
```

Comment: Thank you! I like your solution, simple and handy

Answer (score 1):

There are already numbers associated with characters. You can use these code points with [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#ord).
A short (in terms of lines) solution would be:

```
num_of = lambda s: ord(s) - 97
```

A normal function would be easier to read:

```
def num_of(s):
    return ord(s) - 97
```

Usage:

```
num_of("a") # 0
num_of("z") # 25
```

If it must be a dictionary you can create it without imports like that:

```
{chr(n):n-97 for n in range(ord("a"), ord("z")+1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner with map and enumerate:

```
# given
foo = 'abcxyz'
dict(enumerate(foo))

# returns: {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'x', 4: 'y', 5: 'z'}
```

If you needed it with the characters as the dictionary keys, what comes into my mind is either a dict comprehension...

```
{letter:num for (num,letter) in enumerate(foo) }

# returns {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'z': 3, 'y': 4, 'x': 5}
```

... or a lambda...

```
dict( map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), enumerate(foo)) )

# returns {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'z': 3, 'y': 4, 'x': 5}
```

I feel dict comprehension is *much more* readable than map+lambda+enumerate.

Comment: what if I want it the other way around? I mean like: {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5...

Comment: I guess you can only use dict comprehension or map+lambda. I've updated the answer with an example.